# Passing variables into flow

Tags: visual-workflow, flow

I have two custom buttons on contact, Create Opportunity and Create Adoption Opportunity. The URLs for the buttons are as follows:

`/flow/Create_Opp?varContactId={!Contact.Id}
 /flow/Create_AOpp?varContactId={!Contact.Id}`

They both have a varContactID set to have input/output. I made the very first thing of each flow have a screen that displays the varContactID. The screen gives me a contact ID for AOpp, but not Opp. Everything seems exactly the same.

Is there something I might be missing that stops the contactID from being passed into the flow?

Comment: I have created a completely new flow, adding one element at a time, to see if any of them break it. This new flow seems to work fine, so I'm just going to use it instead. Although I still have no idea what is wrong with the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. You would typically pass variables to a flow using the steps mentioned [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=vpm_designer_resources_variable.htm&language=en_US).

> From Setup, click Create | Workflow & Approvals | Flows and open a new
>   or existing flow.
>
> From the Resources tab, double-click Variable.
>
> Fill out the fields.

The var name should be unique. Did you change that around the 2nd time?

Comment: All three flows (see my comment) had the same var name. 'varContactID'. I double checked the cases even.